# jQuery Reloading Single Loop Animated Gif

Tags: jquery, gif, animated-gif, hubspot

I've built a banner that displays a different single-loop animated gif for each "slide" depending on if the slide on going in reverse or forward.

When the banner loops, I'm having difficulty getting the single-loop animated gif to restart (as to display the animation again).

My HMTL code is

```
<div class="testimonial testimonial-{{name}}">
  <div class="quote-container">
    
{% for item in module.questions_answers %}
     <div class="quote-box"> 
    <div class="image-detail">
   <div class="question_inner">
          <div id="first_load">     
          {% if item.question.src %}
        <img src="{{ item.question.src }}" alt="{{ item.question.alt }}">
          {% endif %}
           </div>
          <div id="previous">   
          {% if item.question2.src %}
            <img src="{{ item.question2.src }}" alt="{{ item.question2.alt }}">
          {% endif %}
          </div>
          <div id="next">
          {% if item.question3.src %}
        <img src="{{ item.question3.src }}" alt="{{ item.question3.alt }}">
          {% endif %}
         </div>
     
     </div>
     </div>
    
      <div class="answer-inner">
        <img src="https://2821482.fs1.hubspotusercontent-na1.net/hubfs/2821482/2023%20-%20Rebrand/yellow-bubble-line.png">
        <h3>{{ item.answer_title }}</h3>
        <p>{{ item.answer_paragraph }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
    
    <div class="quote-arrows">
      <a class="previous">❮</a>
      <a class="next">❯</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My jQuery is as follows (for only the image section):

```
/* Questions Section */
(function($) {

var question_section = function() {

return {

  options: {
    quoteEl      : '.question-inner', //
    autoplay     : true,
    speed        : 0,
  },

  init: function(options, element) {
    this.options = $.extend(this.options, options);
    this.elem = element;
    this.quoteBox = $(this.elem).find($(this.options.quoteEl));
    this.no_of_quotes = this.quoteBox.length;
    this.current = 0;
    this.max = this.no_of_quotes + 1;
    this.autoChange = 0;
    this.firstLoad();
  },

  firstLoad : function () {
    this.attachEvents();
    this.addQuoteDots();
    this.hideQuotes();
    this.displayQuote(this.current);
    $(this.elem).find(".question_inner").addClass("first_load");
    this.autoPlay();
  },
  
  /* automatically rotate quotes */
    autoPlay : function () {
    if(this.options.autoplay == 'true') {
      var t = this;
      t.autoChange = setInterval(function(){ 
        t.nextQuote();
      }, this.options.speed);
    } 
  },

  /* stop automatic rotation */
    stopAutoPlay : function () {
    clearInterval(this.autoChange);
  },

  /* next quote */
  nextQuote : function () {
    $(this.elem).find(".question_inner").addClass("test_next");
    $(this.elem).find(".question_inner").removeClass("test_previous");    
    $(this.elem).find(".question_inner").removeClass("first_load");    
    this.hideQuotes();
    this.current += 1;
    if (this.current === this.no_of_quotes) {
      this.current = 0;
    }
    this.displayQuote(this.current);
  },
  /* previous quote */
  previousQuote : function () {
    $(this.elem).find(".question_inner").addClass("test_previous");
    $(this.elem).find(".question_inner").removeClass("test_next");    
    $(this.elem).find(".question_inner").removeClass("first_load");    
    this.hideQuotes();
    this.current -= 1;
    if (this.current < 0) {
      this.current = this.no_of_quotes - 1;
    }
    this.displayQuote(this.current);
  },
  
  /* hide all quotes */
  hideQuotes : function () {
    this.quoteBox.hide();
  },
  
  /* detach quote */
  detachQuotes: function () {
    this.quoteBox.detach();
  },

  /* display the specific quote n and add active class to dot */
  displayQuote : function (n) {
    this.quoteBox.eq(n).fadeIn("fast");
    $(this.elem).find("ul.quote-dots li").removeClass("active");
    $(this.elem).find("ul.quote-dots li[data-num=" + n + "]").addClass("active");
  },

  /* dynamically add dots equivalent to quotes */
  addQuoteDots : function () {
    if($(this.elem).find("ul.quote-dots").length === 0){
      $('<ul class="quote-dots"></ul>').appendTo($(this.elem));
    }
    for (i=0; i<this.no_of_quotes; i++){
      $(this.elem).find("ul.quote-dots").append("<li data-num=" + i + "></li>");
    }
  },

  attachEvents: function() {

    var self = this;

    $(self.elem).find("ul.quote-dots li").on('click',function() { 
      var current = $(this).data("num");
      self.hideQuotes();
      self.stopAutoPlay();
      self.displayQuote(current);
      self.autoPlay();
    });

    $(self.elem).find(".previous").on('click',function() { 
      self.stopAutoPlay();
      self.previousQuote();
      self.autoPlay();
    });

    $(self.elem).find(".next").on('click',function() {
      self.stopAutoPlay();
      self.nextQuote();
      self.autoPlay();
    });
  }
  };
  };

  $.fn.question_section = function(options) {

    return this.each(function() {
      var tn = new question_section();
      tn.init(options, this);
    });
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: _" I'm having difficulty getting the single-loop animated gif to restart"_ What does that mean? Are you seeing a particular error message? What exactly are you seeing?

Comment: @kmoser there is no particular error, the gif is just not displaying on second load. Since it is set as one-loop I'm thinking I'm going to half to force the div the loop is in to reload for it to restart the gif again, but unsure how to do that since what I've attempted up to this point has not worked.